# Joining two tables in Expression Builder

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003, expressionbuilder

I am a new user to ms access and just now started using MS access 2003. I want to apply equality join in expression builder in a form. I want to populate **Employee.EmployeeLastName** from Employee table when **Employee.EmpNo** = **SalesHistoryToExcelFormRawData.ordSalesRep**

I am trying this:

> =[Employees]![EmpLastName] WHERE( ([SalesHistoryToExcelFormRawData]![ordSalesRep]) = ([Employees]![EmpNo]) )

But I am getting invalid syntax error. Help will be appreciated. I spent a lot of time in googling how to use where clause in expression builder but no luck :( 
Is there any other way I can achieve this.

I am novice to ms access and started using two days ago. Please let me know if my approach is wrong.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please verify which version of Access you are using.

Comment: What is Access 2005? I have not heard of this.

Comment: My bad, its 2003. Apologies I typed it wrongly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably be using `Dlookup()` in your expression. Example: `=Dlookup("[EmpLastName]","[Employees]","[EmpNo]=" & [ordSalesRep]))"`. Read the help for `Dlookup`, as it is very useful in a form context.

Comment: Thanks cowboy, I changed main sql query of the form. (hard way but it worked.)

Thanks

Comment: If a form is read-only (just displaying records), then pulling in additional fields using a JOIN is often simplest. However, be aware that some types of joins will make the resulting dataset read-only, and not all database products will allow you to edit all or part of a joined recordset (Access is very accomodating). Something to keep in mind.